# Accessing javascript variables set in Callback function of a PageMethod call

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, pagemethods

In a click event, I invoke a PageMethods request, which contains two callback functions: OnServerValidationSuccess and OnServerValidationFailure. I also try and set create an object called `clientResult`;

```
    var clientResult = { rc: "", msg: "" };

    $('#btnSave').click( function () {
        PageMethods.ServerValidateCreateCompany(companyName, domainName, country, OnServerValidationSuccess, OnServerValidationFailure);
        alert(clientResult.rc); //this is null!
});
```

In the OnServerValidationSuccess, the result parameter contains the asynchronous response. And in there I try to assign it to `clientResult`.

```
//On Success callback
function OnServerValidationSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
    clientResult = result;
    if (clientResult.msg.length != 0) {
        document.getElementById('resMsg').innerHTML = clientResult.msg;
        $('#resMsg').addClass('warning');
    }
}
```

I assign the `result` to local `clientResult` variable in the callback function. It should contain the fully formed server response, which is sent correctly by the server-side WebMethod.
However, it remains null or empty after PageMethod is called.
What must I do in order to assign the variable set in the callback to a local variable so that I can access it?

Comment: What does your PageMethod look like? It's hard to tell without seeing that.

Comment: On a side note, I would advocate using an HttpHandler over a PageMethod. It's going to be a lot less overhead than using a Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be assigning the value to `clientResult` correctly, you're just accessing it too early.

You're making an asynchronous/non-blocking call which means that it returns immediately but continues to work in the background. So your JavaScript immediately returns from the call to `PageMethods.ServerValidateCreateCompany` and moves on to the `alert`. But your request hasn't had time to complete and your success callback (`OnServerValidationSuccess`) hasn't even run yet so you get `undefined` or `null`.

You should invoke whatever function is going to process the response *in* the `OnServerValidationSuccess` function which is where the response will be received. Perhaps something like this (you already seem to doing something with `msg`, just move your work with `rc` here as well)

```
//On Success callback
function OnServerValidationSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
    clientResult = result;
    alert(clientResult.rc); //this will work
    process(clientResult); //process the response here
    if (clientResult.msg.length != 0) {
        document.getElementById('resMsg').innerHTML = clientResult.msg;
        $('#resMsg').addClass('warning');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I have not done all the handling in the `OnServerValidationSuccess` is because the `PageMethod` is called in a click event handler and the response contains logic  to conditionally return true/false for form validating and submitting. Which is why I need the scope of the `clientResult` variable to be made outside of the callback method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the scope of the `clientResult` is still the same as before, it's just being accessed at a different place.

Comment: I think I see what you need - you want to submit/cancel submission of the form depending on whether the server says the entries are valid and you want to use the `clientResult.rc` value as the check. Off the top of my head, you might force the request to be synchronous but that's usually NOT recommended because it'll cause your page to lock up until the response comes back.

Comment: You were right, synchronous was the way to go.
I abandoned using PageMethods because it is asynchronous by default and this behaviour can't be overridden.
So I went with the much lower-level jquery $.ajax(), and assigned the 'async' property to false. Also it doesn't inject the patch with loads of unwanted script dross to enable it to work. jquery saved the day again!

Comment: I meant to write "inject the page" not "inject the patch".